# Bad Luck island dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is question in [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com) name bad luck island this is a kind of dynamic programming problems here is the link of question
[D. Bad Luck Island](http://codeforces.com/contest/540/problem/D)
I didn't understand the problem currently so I read it's tutorial the  here is the tutorial

> Let's count the values dp[r][s][p] — the probability of the situation when r rocks, s scissors and p papers are alive. The initial probability is 1, and in order to calculate the others we should perform the transitions.
>
> Imagine we have r rocks, s scissors and p papers. Let's find the probability of the rock killing scissors (the other probabilities are calculated in the same way). The total number of the possible pairs where one species kills the other one is rs + rp + sp, and the number of possible pairs (rock, scissors) is rs. As all meetings are equiprobable, the probability we want to find is . This is the probability with which we go the the state dp[r][s — 1][p], with the number of scissors less by one.
>
> In the end, for example, to get the probability of the event that the rocks are alive, we should sum all values dp[i][0][0] for i from 1 to r (the same goes to the other species).

I understood most of it but just one part it says that `dp[r][s][p] — the probability of the situation when r rocks, s scissors and p papers are alive` what this sentence mean and what probability does he talk about?
I just didn't get this part.
Is there any one who can explain what is the definition of `dp[r][s][p]`?

Answer (score 0):

`dp[r][s][p]` is the probability (over all possible sequences of random events) that there are **exactly** `r` rocks, `s` scissors and `p` papers alive on the island. The point is if at any point there is a situation where `r!=0` and `s==0` and `p==0` then this is a terminal state. We want to calculate the probability of reaching this terminal state. Since there are `r` possible terminal states where only rocks are alive we want to calculate the sum of these which gives the probability of reaching a terminal state with only rocks.

The way to actually perform the calculation is to build a 3d array of dimension `r*s*p` and populate it by starting at `dp[r][s][p]=1` (since this is the initial state of the problem). Then proceed to calculate `dp[r-1][s][p]`, `dp[r][s-1][p]` and `dp[r][s][p-1]` as these are the three possible transitions. Then recurse for each case until you reach `dp[0][0][0]` and then just output the sum of `dp[i][0][0]`.

Comment: what probability exactly are you talking about the probability that Rocks win if it's what is the dp[r][0][0] !!!?

Comment: No the probability that on the island there are exactly r, s and p people.

Comment: So you say probability!! probability of what ??

Comment: Probability of at any point having r, s and p living people. So for example if you start out with 2, 2, 2. Then dp[2][1][2] is 1/3 because 1/3 of the time the rock will die, 1/3 the paper will die and 1/3 the scissors will die. If the rock died you will never have 2 living rocks and 1 living paper because there is only one living rock.

Comment: So basically you take the probability over all possible games (i.e. run the game with every possible random outcome of events) that you will reach a certain state. This is: #of times a state is reached/#possible games. So in the example above in 1/3 of all games starting at 2, 2, 2 you will reach the state 2, 1, 2.

Comment: you mean dp[r][s][p] is actually three probability and always these three are the same ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82201/discussion-between-daniel-v-and-benjy-kessler).

Answer (score 0):

You overthink too much...

`dp[r][s][p]` means one and only one thing:

The Probability of "There is `r` rocks **AND** `s` scissors **AND** `p` papers exist on the island".

This means that when two of them are 0 e.g. dp[0][0][x] means "there is only `x` papers alive now, other two species extinct!"